# only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: pycharm, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class RobotArm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = 100

    def main(self):
        print('start')
        x = np.linspace(1, self.time, num=self.time)
        y = self.count(x, 1)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()

    def count(self, x: object, num: object) -> object:
        t = (x - 1) * (2 * math.pi / self.omega) / 100
        self.y = {}
        self.y[1] = self.theta[1] * math.cos(self.omega * x) - self.theta[1]
        return t[num]
    # ниже приведен лаунчер для запуска основного кода
def start():
    case = RobotArm()
    print('test start')
    case.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

при запуске выдает ошибки:

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe" C:/Users/ 
Мазур/Desktop/python_project/robot_arm_louncher.py
test start
Traceback (most recent call last):
start
  File "C:/Users/Мазур/Desktop/python_project/robot_arm_louncher.py", line 9, 
in <module>
    start()
  File "C:/Users/Мазур/Desktop/python_project/robot_arm_louncher.py", line 6, 
in start
    case.main()
  File "C:\Users\Мазур\Desktop\python_project\robot_arm.py", line 25, in main
    y = self.count(x, 1)
  File "C:\Users\Мазур\Desktop\python_project\robot_arm.py", line 32, in 
count
    self.y[1] = self.theta[1] * math.cos(self.omega * x) - self.theta[1]
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: помогите разобраться в чем ошибка

Comment: Наверное, это исправит: `math.cos(self.omega * x[1])` либо `math.cos(self.omega[1] * x[1])`, смотря что у вас в `self.omega` вообще находится. Я так понимаю, вместо `1` везде должно быть `num`, это вы для отладки поменяли, да?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код нельзя воспроизвести, потому что в классе RobotArm нет theta, omega и еще чего-то. Чтобы точнее ответить на вопрос нужны эти данные.

Если говорить об ошибке в целом, то проблема следующая. Ваша ошибка сообщает, что вы передаете в функцию массив, хотя она ожидает единичный элемент. Например

```
from numpy import linspace
from math import sin, pi

x = linspace(-pi, pi)
sin(x)
```

Результат:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-9832177eb52e> in <module>()
      1 from math import sin
      2 
----> 3 sin(x)

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

`sin(x)` не ожидает вектор значений.